# Find the most "viable" sequence of colored balls

Tags: probability, statistics

You are presented with a set of sequences of colored balls (the order matters of course). For example, you may be given $\{(green, green, blue), (blue, red, purple),\ldots\}$. And because it is a set, no sequence appears twice.

You are asked to pick a sequence of colored balls $S$ out of the given set such that $S$ is the most likely one to stay within the set of sequences once it is altered. By 'altered' I mean a change of color, which can occur with equal probability to one or more balls, e.g., $(green, green, blue)$ may be altered to $(purple, green, blue)$ (here, a single color change took place, but there can be more in general).

**Solution (?)**

Intuitively I was thinking that I should construct a sequence of balls based on the most frequently appearing color for each candidate ball in the sequence, in particular, maximizing said frequency among all balls in a sequence (because the most frequent color for a candidate ball may not be part of a solution). For example, if I was given the following set:

$\{(green, green, blue), (green, red, purple), (purple, yellow, blue)\}$

then I would construct the sequence $(green, whatever, blue)$, because $green$ and $blue$ essentially appear twice in their respective positions. And for $whatever$ here I would chose $green$ so that I have a sequence from the given set. So, my solution would be $(green, green, blue)$.

Is this the correct way to approach a solution? It feels natural to me, but I have been overthinking it.

Comment: It depends... what is the relationship between the 'altered' sequence and the 'original' sequence? If the altered sequence is not required to keep any of the original colors in the sequence, then because the final sequence is random, it may not matter what sequence you choose. Every sequence could be 'altered' to any other sequence with equal probability (if the distribution is uniform).

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Let's say you picked a sequence of 10 colored balls. The alteration (a single one) occurs as follows. First, we chose with equal probability a number between 1 and 10. Then, for that number, say $x$, we chose with equal probability a sequence of $x$ colors (these can happen to be the same as in your picked sequence).

Comment: Then, I believe your intuition is correct, but I think it would be complex to prove it.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Thank you :) Yeah, I think so too. For the moment I am not concerned much with the proof though. However, I thought that my problem would correspond to some already known problem in mathematics/statistics. For some reason it reminds me of something, but I cannot put my finger on it. It feels like a natural problem to solve in various settings.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe As I have been putting more thought into this, I don't think some universal strategy exists for solving the problem. Considering frequencies of appearing colors may give a good approximation, but in the end one might have to take into account all possible alterations for each sequence to really see which one is best.

Comment: That may be. I am not discounting the possibility, but due to linearity of expectation, it seems probable that your initial intuition was correct.